# Queue requests when network offline using react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I save requests when the device is offline?
I thought about making a queue and doing them when the device is connected, I saw some solutions using Redux, however they were using outdated libs.
I was wondering if there is a method of doing this in a simpler way without Redux, but if not, if you have any examples to show me.